# Client/Server Android App: Two AsyncTask. Problems

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

This is my application: 1 Activity, 2 AsyncTask (once to send request, once to wait the responses).

```
1) onCreate()
    AsyncTask1.execute() 
    - AsyncTask1.doInBackground() wait for incomng connection. Works!
2) onClick()
    AsyncTask2.execute()
    - AsyncTask2.doInBackground() never executed.
```

How can solve this? Why the AsyncTask2.doInBackground() doesn't work?

There is a better pattern to create a C/S application?

Comment: Is this Activity a server app?  A peer-to-peer app?  Or a client app?  It is unclear.  Also, are you hooking up a Button with setOnClickListener() to onClick() and then tapping/clicking it?  AsyncTasks should queue up and execute either in serial or parallel, depending on API level.

Comment: The activity is a server/client app. The client side send an serializable object to the server. This one re-transmit the object with additional data to the activity that have a serversocket,also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is this:

```
task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

instead of

```
task.execute();
```

[Android SDK Link - Executor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29)

Answer (score 1):

Read docs on AsyncTask class, it says that since android 3.0 AsyncTasks are serialized:

"Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution."

So basicly AsyncTask2 is waiting for AsyncTask1 to end which will not happen since it is waiting for connection. You can use executeOnExecutor method to run AsyncTask in paraller - but it is available since API 11.

You should consider using Services or ExecutorService:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html